# Using terraform remote state in s3 with multiple folders

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am currently using the default workspace and my folder structure is like this -

```
dev
        ├── app
        │   └── main.tf
        ├── mysql
        │   └── main.tf
        └── vpc
            └── main.tf
```

I have a s3 backend created and it works fine for a single folder

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "mybucket"
    key            = "global/s3/mykey/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-wellness-nonprod"
    encrypt        = true
  }
}
```

I am struggling on how to include this back-end config in all the folders, like i want to use the same backend s3 bucket in app, mysql and vpc (diff keys for Dynamodb) but while this works in one folder , in the second folder terraform wants to delete both S3 bucket and Dynamodb.

Comment: How are you running this? It looks like you have three applications, so the bucket will look like: `[app | mysql | vpc]/global/s3/mykey/terraform.tfstate`

Comment: so i should create "folders" inside of buckets  - so my bucket key in the backend block should be like mybucket-app, mybucket-mysql etc? I am just running terraform init and terraform apply/plan

Comment: Based on the files you provided, you have the `backend` configuration repeated three times, that should do it. If you get into each directory and run the commands, everything should be fine. And no, you should not have to do anything "manually" on that bucket, Terraform will manage all those files for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work , terraform does find it but when i plan it in a new folder wants to destroy the old backend and then obviously everything fails

Answer (score 9):

I recommend you use `module` structure in terraform code.

like :

```
   dev
    ├──modules
    │    ├── app
    │    │   └── app.tf
    │    ├── mysql
    │    │   └── mysql.tf
    │    └── vpc
    │        └── vpc.tf
    └──main.tf
```

main.tf :

```
module "app" {
  source = "./modules/app"
...
}

module "mysql" {
  source = "./modules/mysql"
...
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "./modules/vpc"
...
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you want to apply/destroy each module :

```
terraform apply -target module.app
terraform destroy -target module.app
```

> See :
>
> Here's [a repository](https://github.com/gnokoheat/aws-serverless-data-pipeline-by-terraform) using `module` structure.

Comment: Thanks, can i have nested modules? because some of my code is already inside modules in subfolders

Comment: then try use another workspace. it can make same module to different resources. and you can use duplicate module as just change module's name in same workspace.

Comment: so it mostly works but i have a variable in a module file, how do i pass them from the main file? It is a required variable

Comment: terraform plan -var="password=mypass" gives me an error `A variable named "password" was assigned on the command line, but the
root module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value, add a
"variable" block to the configuration.` , its defined at the module level

Comment: did you review [a repository](https://github.com/gnokoheat/aws-serverless-data-pipeline-by-terraform) ? you can find how can setting variables in `modules` with `main.tf`.